# configure htmlpurifier with html5 and css3

Tags: php, html, css, htmlpurifier

I am using htmlpurifier. I have some doubts which are as below.

1- My config file contain

```
$config->set('HTML.Trusted' ,true);
$config->set('CSS.Trusted', true);
```

But a simple Google is landing me to pages where there are recommendation not to use  *.Trusted as "true".

I am not able to understand why should we should not set *.Trusted to true? Can you please explain me. Because if I remove it than I wont get inline css? Even CSS.AllowTricky is not helping.

2- I found that HTML5 and CSS3 selectors are not allowed.

like the code at htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier/Filter/ExtractStyleBlocks.php

```
 //      - No Unicode support
                //      - No escapes support
                //      - No string support (by proxy no attrib support)
                //      - element_name is matched against allowed
                //        elements (some people might find this
                //        annoying...)
                //      - Pseudo-elements one of :first-child, :link,
                //        :visited, :active, :hover, :focus

                // handle ruleset
                $selectors = array_map('trim', explode(',', $selector));
                $new_selectors = array();
                foreach ($selectors as $sel) {
                    //some code to filter css selectors
                }
```

do not contain any code which can allow selectors like '[class*="grid-"]'. Hence all such css is getting removed after purification. Is ther some way to allow all CSS3?

3- Is there some way to allow all HTML 5 tags? for example if we have html like

```
<section class="mainhead">
<div class="subhead"> </div> </section>
```

then purifier removes   and  due to which some css like

```
.mainhead .subhead { //some css}
```

wont work.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? If so, would you kindly post it here?

Answer (score 1):

1. Setting `HTML.Trusted` to `true` enables unsafe elements, such as `script` and forms. If you, for example, want to allow forms, but don't want to allow scripts, just add them to `HTML.ForbiddenElements`:

   ```php
   $config->set('HTML.Trusted', true);
   $config->set('HTML.ForbiddenElements', ['script']);
   ```
2. CSS3 selectors are not supported - there is a [pending Pull Request](https://github.com/ezyang/htmlpurifier/pull/174), but it has been inactive for more than a year (as of Aug 2019). I don't think this will change any soon.
3. As for HTML5 support - you can use an extension package https://github.com/xemlock/htmlpurifier-html5 (which I'm the author of), which adds spec compliant definitions of HTML5 elements. It's usage is almost the same the bare HTML Purifier - you just have to replace `HTMLPurifier_Config` with `HTMLPurifier_HTML5Config`.